# Error when excuting SELECT CASE

Tags: sql-server

When I run this query I get this error:

> Procedure sp_GET_RANDOM_QUESTIONS, Line 40
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
>   Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_GET_RANDOM_QUESTIONS, Line 52
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

This is a stored procedure, which is meant to give random questions, the @easy, @medium, @hard are the number of questions that'll be randomized.
If the user chooses to just give a @num, I'll divide that number by 3 (the 3 dificulties) and get those random questions.

```
SELECT  case
WHEN @num=0 THEN (
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT top (@easy) * from TBL_PERGUNTAS as p where p.category=1 order by NEWID()) as a
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT top (@medium) * from TBL_PERGUNTAS as p where p.category=2 order by NEWID()) as b
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT top (@hard) * from TBL_PERGUNTAS as p where p.category=3 order by NEWID()) as c)
    else (
    SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT top (@num/3) * from TBL_PERGUNTAS as p where p.category=1 order by NEWID()) as a
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT top (@num/3) * from TBL_PERGUNTAS as p where p.category=2 order by NEWID()) as b
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT top (@num/3) * from TBL_PERGUNTAS as p where p.category=3 order by NEWID()) as c )
END
```

Comment: CASE is not for control-of-flow (it must return a single value); if you want one or another set of results use IF/ELSE

Comment: Your code is a mess to say the least. The problem here is you are trying to use a case expression to control flow which doesn't work. You need to use IF/ELSE logic here. Also you should avoid the sp_ prefix. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have stated, you need to use `IF/ELSE` for control-of-flow, try this:

```
IF @num=0 THEN 
BEGIN
    SELECT top (@easy) * 
    FROM TBL_PERGUNTAS as p 
    WHERE p.category=1 
    ORDER BY NEWID()

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT top (@medium) * 
    FROM TBL_PERGUNTAS as p 
    WHERE p.category=2 
    ORDER BY NEWID()

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT top (@hard) * 
    FROM TBL_PERGUNTAS as p 
    WHERE p.category=3 
    ORDER BY NEWID())
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT top (@num/3) * 
    FROM TBL_PERGUNTAS as p 
    WHERE p.category=1 
    ORDER BY NEWID()

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT top (@num/3) * 
    FROM TBL_PERGUNTAS as p
    WHERE p.category=2 
    ORDER BY NEWID()

    UNION ALL  

    SELECT top (@num/3) * 
    FROM TBL_PERGUNTAS as p 
    WHERE p.category=3 
    ORDER BY NEWID())
END
```